# Using Batch Project Script to read from text file as Input to ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, batch

I was wondering how I would modify the code of the Batch Project script shown below, to read from a text file of shapefile names as input. A sample of the textfile is shown under the code:

```
#Import required modules
import ConversionUtils, time

#Define message constants so they may be translated easily
msgWorkspace = ConversionUtils.gp.GetIDMessage(86109) # Message "Output workspace does not exist: "
msgCoordinateSystem = ConversionUtils.gp.GetIDMessage(86110)  #Message "Must Enter a Spatial Reference or Template Feature Class."
msgFail =  ConversionUtils.gp.GetIDMessage(86111) # Message "Failed to project "

#Set the input datasets
inputs = ConversionUtils.gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
# The list is split by semicolons ";"
inputs = ConversionUtils.SplitMultiInputs(inputs)  

#Set the output workspace
output_workspace = ConversionUtils.gp.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Set the spatial reference
output_coordinate_system = ConversionUtils.gp.GetParameterAsText(2)

#Set the template dataset
template_dataset = ConversionUtils.gp.GetParameterAsText(3)

#Set the transformation
transformation = ConversionUtils.gp.GetParameterAsText(4)
#Message 86112   "Projecting multiple datasets ..."
ConversionUtils.gp.SetProgressor("step",ConversionUtils.gp.GetIDMessage(86112), 0, len(inputs))

if (output_coordinate_system == "" or output_coordinate_system == "#") and (template_dataset == "" or template_dataset == "#"):
    raise ConversionUtils.GPError(msgCoordinateSystem) 
elif (output_coordinate_system != "") and (output_coordinate_system != "#"):
    sr = output_coordinate_system
elif (template_dataset != "") and (template_dataset != "#"):
    dsc = ConversionUtils.gp.Describe(template_dataset)
    sr = dsc.SpatialReference

for input in inputs:
    try:
        outdata = ConversionUtils.GenerateOutputName(input, output_workspace)
        #Message 86113 "Projecting "
        ConversionUtils.gp.SetProgressorLabel(ConversionUtils.gp.GetIDMessage(86113) + input)        
        ConversionUtils.gp.Project_management(input, outdata, sr, transformation) 
        #Message 86114 "Projected %s to %s successfully."
        ConversionUtils.gp.AddMessage(ConversionUtils.gp.GetIDMessage(86114) % (input, outdata))

    except Exception, ErrorDesc:
        msgWarning = msgFail + "%s" % input
        msgStr = ConversionUtils.gp.GetMessages(2)
        ConversionUtils.gp.AddWarning(ConversionUtils.ExceptionMessages(msgWarning, msgStr, ErrorDesc))

    ConversionUtils.gp.SetProgressorPosition()

time.sleep(0.5)
```

Text File Sample:

> C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\Geochem
>   Merged\Pyramid_PanCon.shp
>   C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\Geochem
>   Merged\Pyramid_Rocks.shp
>   C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\Geochem
>   Merged\Pyramid_Silts.shp
>   C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\Geochem
>   Merged\Pyramid_Soils.shp
>   C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\test2\mod\interpretive
>   alteration_point.shp
>   C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\test2\mod\interpretive
>   alteration_polyline.shp
>   C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\test2\mod\Interpretive
>   Pyramid geology_polyline.shp
>   C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\test2\mod\Interpretive
>   Pyramid geology_region.shp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your block:

```
#Set the input datasets
inputs = ConversionUtils.gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
# The list is split by semicolons ";"
inputs = ConversionUtils.SplitMultiInputs(inputs)
```

With:

```
inputs = [item.replace('\n', '') for item in open(filename).readlines()]
```

Where `filename` is your file with the list of SHP ("Text File Sample").

Comment: Awesome, this worked like a charm.  Thanks, so much.

Comment: +1, much better than my lame answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Open up the file, read it into memory, iterate through each line, and do something with the input. I put your text file sample into a file called inputs.txt:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("inputs.txt").readlines()
>>> for line in f:
...     print line
...
C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\Geochem Merged\Pyramid_PanC
on.shp C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\Geochem Merged\Pyram
id_Rocks.shp

C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\Geochem Merged\Pyramid_Silt
s.shp C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\Geochem Merged\Pyrami
d_Soils.shp

C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\test2\mod\interpretive alte
ration_point.shp C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\test2\mod\
interpretive alteration_polyline.shp

C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\test2\mod\Interpretive Pyra
mid geology_polyline.shp

C:\Users\revresources\scratch\shapefiles\Test_Output\test2\mod\InterpretivePyram
idgeology_region.shp
>>>
```